# Insert chinese using odata client to azure sql

Tags: sql, azure, windows-phone, odata, collation

I am using azure aql as a backend for a windows phone app I am writing. I expose the db using odata protocol, and using the odata client library to read and write db. I am having a problem to insert Chinese strings. Each chinese charatcter will show up as "?" in the db. 
The following is the code. Using the debugger, i can tell, the chinese character is still in the write format before the BeginSaveChanges call. The according field in the db is defined as nvarchar. I can put chinese no problem from the web management portal.

```
NewJoke.Title = Regex.Replace(NewJoke.Title, "'", "''");
            NewJoke.Content = Regex.Replace(NewJoke.Content, "'", "''");
            dsc = new DataServiceContext(funnyJokesUri);
            try
            {
                //Name of the entity goes into the first attribute of the AddObject method followed by the entity itself
                //INSERTING
                dsc.AddObject("Jokes", NewJoke);
                dsc.BeginSaveChanges(insertJoke_Completed, dsc);
            }
```

Comment: The ? Character shows up where, in the database or on the phone? Does it get lost when your displaying it?

Comment: The chinese lost in the db. If I put chinese in the db through the web portal, the chinese were displayed fine on the phone. I just can't insert chinese into the db.

Comment: Through what web portal? From where are you inserting into the db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the collation for Chinese on the column, I think.  More...  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlazure/archive/2010/06/11/10023650.aspx

BTW -- I wasn't clear on reading your question -- it sounds like you're saying the db stores the chinese fine when you use the web portal to insert it; but presumably, it does not store the chinese when you use some other method for inserting it. (?)  Is that what you're saying?

Comment: yes. When I am trying to insert programmatically from my application using odata client library, it shows up in the db as "?"